# Click event is not working inside jquery easyui multi tab

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I have added some user input fields inside jquery easyui multitab .To store the user input fields into database i have added submit button also.But button click event is not happening instead the current tab in which submit button is available is redirecting to Home tab on click event ..Here is the user input form that i have added into the current tab of multitab..

```
     <div id="Reservationuserform" class="panel panel-primary" style=" margin:-10px; display:none;margin-left:-16px; margin-top:-15px; margin-right:-16px;">
     <div class="panel-heading">
     <h3 class="panel-title">Reservation</h3>
      </div>
      <div class="panel-body">
      <button type="submit" id="reserve" class="btn btn-primary pull-right" >Reserve</button>
        <br />
        <br />
     <div class="row">
     <div class="col-md-3">
     <label for="Booking Id">Booking Id</label>
     <input type="BookingId"  id="1" placeholder="Enter Booking Id">
     </div>
     </div>
     </div>
```

and here is the click event ..

```
 $("#reserve").click(function () {
        alert("hello");
 });
```

but the issue is that i am not getting any alert message ..
Please help me to get the correct click event .Thanks..

Comment: please provide a fiddle

Comment: @MaxZoom As the easyui multitab contains outer jquery files so i am not able to create the fiddle for it..If you want the full page code i will send it to you ..Please provide your email id..

Comment: show the head of the file please

Comment: @SariRahal Will you provide your email id so that i can send the code at your id..Please help me ..Thanks

Comment: Please edit your post and put the complete `html` and `js` code here so we can help you.

Answer (score 0):

missing the last/most out closing div tag. the correct html code should be as this,

```
<div id="Reservationuserform" class="panel panel-primary" 
     style="margin:-10px; margin-left:-16px; margin-top:-15px; margin-right:-16px;">    
    <div class="panel-heading">
        <h3 class="panel-title">Reservation</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="panel-body">
        <button type="submit" id="reserve" class="btn btn-primary pull-right" >Reserve</button>
        <br />
        <br />
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-3">
                <label for="Booking Id">Booking Id</label>
                <input type="BookingId"  id="1" placeholder="Enter Booking Id" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

 $("#reserve").click(function () {
        alert("hello");
 });
```

Since you set the most out div style as display:none. So everything (including Reserve button) is hidden.

[**FIDDLE**](https://jsfiddle.net/User86745458/cw9o2z2j/)